# Remove the lines before and after the exact match - linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a file like this in /etc/test/host.conf :

```
# this is a test
host = example.com
private = 192.168.1.1
# end of test

# this is a test
host = example.com
private = 192.168.1.2 
# end of test
```

I want to find the "private = 192.168.1.1" line and delete it and also I want to delete the two lines before and 1 line after that.

I searched before, but I could not find a sed command that is suitable for me.

Comment: Is `sed` required, or any other solution can do ?

Comment: It doesn't matter my friend. I am looking for the least complexity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find and delete the "private = 192.168.1.1" line and the two lines before and one line after it, you can use the following commands:

```
# Set the file path
file_path="/etc/test/host.conf"

# Use the "grep" command to find the line containing "private = 192.168.1.1"
line_number=`grep -n "private = 192.168.1.1" $file_path`

# Extract the line number from the output of the "grep" command
line_number=${line_number%:*}

# Use the "sed" command to delete the line containing "private = 192.168.1.1" and the two lines before and one line after it
sed -i "$((line_number-2)),$((line_number+1))d" $file_path
```

The first command uses the "grep" command to find the line number of the line containing "private = 192.168.1.1" in the file at the specified path. The second command extracts the line number from the output of the "grep" command. The third command uses the "sed" command to delete the line containing "private = 192.168.1.1" and the two lines before and one line after it.

Answer (score 1):

Attempt with a bash script and a circular buffer (array) of 4 lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

lines=()
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line ; do
    # accumulate up to 4 lines in an array
    lines+=("$line")
    if [ ${#lines[@]} -eq 4 ] ; then
        # if the pattern is detected in the 3rd line, drop the accumulated lines
        if [ $(echo ${lines[2]} | grep "private = 192.168.1.1" | wc -l) -eq 1 ] ; then
            lines=()
        else
            # otherwise output the 1st line and frop it from the array
            echo "${lines[0]}"
            lines=("${lines[@]:1}")
        fi
    fi
done
# at the end output the possible remaining lines
while [ ${#lines[@]} -gt 0 ] ; do
    echo "${lines[0]}"
    lines=("${lines[@]:1}")
done
```

Won't work if the lines contain double quotes `"`, though (edit: looks like it works even with quotes, actually)

Comment: Fragile pieces: (1) [`while read line`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/108618). (2) [`echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618). (3) [unquoted variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). (4) `.` in a regex is special (consider `grep -Fx`).

Comment: Creating such script and fixing all flaws and potential flaws in it may be a good exercise of what you can do in a shell and how things work together (and how they fail). Still IMO a `while read` loop will never be a really good solution here. This is why I think so: [*Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716) I used to process text by looping in a shell, then I learned the right tools. Been there, done that, so I'm not going to downvote your answer. I just wanted to let you know why I'm not going to upvote the answer either.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I fully understand a non-upvote, but I would not understand a downvote. When programming, a good enough solution for a given problem can do. The given problem here was the example provided by the OP. I have been using shell loops to process text files for years: I don't pretend this is a universal solution that can fit all problems, but it always fitted my needs one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution with `sed`

```
sed '

: start
/\n.*\n.*\n/ b ready
N
b start

: ready
s_.*\n.*\nprivate = 192\.168\.1\.1\n.*__
/./ P
D

' /etc/test/host.conf
```

---

#### Explanation

For multi-line operations in `sed`, a scheme of "NPD" is useful. In your case I started with a loop between `: start` (`start` being an arbitrary label) and `b start` ("go to the label"). The loop appends lines (`N`) to the pattern space until `\n.*\n.*\n` matches. `b ready` jumps out of the loop as soon as there are exactly three newline characters in the pattern space (i.e. four lines; the last line in the pattern space is never terminated by a newline character).

The code reaches `: ready` when there are exactly four lines in the pattern space. Next `s` will replace all four lines with nothing iff the third line exactly matches `private = 192\.168\.1\.1` (dots are special, they need to be escaped to literally match dots).

Now the pattern space is either empty or it still contains the four lines.

Sole `P` prints the pattern space up to the first embedded newline. If there is no embedded newline, `P` works like `p`, i.e. it prints the whole pattern space and an implicit newline. Now:

- if our pattern space is empty (the four lines were deleted by `s`), we don't want this implicit newline;
- but if the pattern space is not empty, we want to move our four-line window by one line.

`/./ P` is a conditional `P`. `/./` tests if the pattern space contains at least one character (it may even be a newline character between empty lines). The `P` command will be performed iff the test succeeds. If the test fails, nothing will be printed in this step.

Sole `D` deletes the pattern space up to the first embedded newline and restarts cycle (without reading a new line of input). But if there is no embedded newline, `D` works like `d`, i.e. it deletes the whole pattern space and starts a new cycle (with reading a new line of input). Now:

- if our pattern space is empty (the four lines were deleted by `s`) then `D` will start a new cycle, one new line of input will be put into the pattern space;
- but if the pattern space is not empty then `D` will delete what `P` has just printed, the pattern space will contain three lines.

Restarting cycle or starting a new cycle means executing from the beginning. Regardless if there is one line in the pattern space or three, the loop will append lines to the pattern space until there are four of them, only then the code will jump to `: ready`. This way the four-line window will move through the whole file.

---

#### Notes

- Automatic printing of pattern space works here exactly as you expect. `P` is responsible for printing lines when the four-line window advances; automatic printing of pattern space is responsible for printing remaining lines (if any) at the end of the file.
- Use [`-i`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92895/108618) if you want. The code may be like:

  ```
  sed -i.bak '
  …
  ' /etc/test/host.conf
  ```

  I advise you to test without `-i` first.
- You wrote:

  > I want to find the `private = 192.168.1.1` line and delete it and also I want to delete the two lines before and one line after that.

  My code is "all or nothing", it deletes lines in packs of four. I mean if there is no "line after" or if there are less than "two lines before" then even "the `private = 192.168.1.1` line" won't be deleted.
- The code does not stop after deleting lines at the first match, it is able to delete more than one pack of lines.
- If matching packs of four lines overlap then not all of them will be deleted. E.g. this snippet:

  ```
  foo
  bar
  # this is a test
  host = example.com
  private = 192.168.1.1
  # overlapping
  host = example.edu
  private = 192.168.1.1
  # end of test
  ```

  will be transformed to:

  ```
  foo
  bar
  host = example.edu
  private = 192.168.1.1
  # end of test
  ```

  because after deleting any matching pack of four lines the algorithm reads at least four new lines before it can delete anything more.